# My session variables are not assigned correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I have a form where users enter details on themselves (including email). The data is stored and then an AUTO_INCREMENT column assigns a unique ID for the user.

I want to use this unique ID as a session variable so that I can track the users progress on the site.

This is what I have at the moment and its not working:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM user_responses WHERE email='$email'";

$result = mysqli_query($qry);

$member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$_SESSION['SESS_USERID'] = $member['userid'];

echo $_SESSION['SESS_USERID'];

session_write_close();
```

I think that I've selected a row in the tbl where the email address is the same as what has just been processed $email is the sanitised id for the email text input. The I've run it to store it into $result. I fetch the array for it and then assign the userid.

Its not working because I get this error:

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\bootstrap\instructions.php on line 36

Comment: did you start the session ? `session_start()`

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: you have `session_write_close();` at the end of your code. So do we have to assume that you have `session_start();` at the top of your code?

Comment: `session_write_close` rarely needed

Comment: Okay I have session_start(); and it records something as the session id but its not the userid that I want. What have I done wrong?

Comment: @user3504462 maybe the field name of the id is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have `session_start();` at the top of you PHP code, then you will be able to use `$_SESSION[]`

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['my_session'];
?>
```